# Reflexive Besov spaces Bs,p,q

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

I don't know whether the Besov space $B^s_{p,q}$ with $1<p,q<\infty$ is reflexive or not? Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3):

Hans Triebel: *Theory of Function spaces* (1983), page 179. The dual of $B_{p,q}^s$ is (as one expects naively) $B_{p',q'}^{-s}$ where $p'$, $q'$ are the conjugate exponents.

Comment: No: true only if $1\le p,q<+\infty.$

Comment: Of course, but the OP asked for the case $1<p,q<\infty$.